# Boundary regularity of the solution of a Poisson equation in a polyhedron

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, laplacian, polyhedra, regularity

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open
- $f\in L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$
- $u\in H_0^1(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ with $$-\langle\nabla\phi,\nabla u\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}=\langle\phi,f\rangle_{L^2(\Lambda)}\;\;\;\text{for all }\phi\in C_c^\infty(\Lambda)\tag1$$

It's well-known (see, for example, [1]) that if $\partial\Lambda\in C^2$, then $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$. Moreover (see [2]), if $d=2$ and $\partial\Lambda$ is "polygonal", we obtain $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$ as well.

Now I'm interested in the case where $\Lambda$ is (bounded, open and) connected and $\partial\Lambda$ is Lipschitz. It's fine for me, if we additionally assume that $d\le 3$. However, I doubt that these assumptions suffice to conclude.

So, if that's indeed the case, is there any chance to show $u\in H^2(\Lambda)$, if we assume that $\Lambda$ is a [polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyhedron)?

---

[1]: Lawrence C. Evans, *Partial Differential Equations*, Theorem 6.3.4
[2]: Pierre Grisvard, *Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains*, Theorem 4.3.1.4

Comment: You quote Grisvard, but seem to overlook that his Theorem 3.2.1.2 does not need $d=2$, only convexity of the domain.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Indeeed, I didn't noticed that theorem. I didn't read the chapter yet. Is the theorem applicable for $Au:=\Delta u$, $u\in\mathcal D(A):=\left\{u\in H_0^1(\Lambda):u\text{ admits a weak Laplacian }\Delta u\in L^2(\Lambda)\right\}$, and $\Lambda$ being just bounded, convex and open (without any assumption on the boundary)?

Comment: use seperation of variables on a cone in $R^2$ with opening $ \alpha>0$ to look for harmonic functions in the cone which have zero Dirichlet BC.  Probably when $ \pi< \alpha < 2 \pi$ i would assume the resulting solution is not in $H^2$ in any neighborhood of the vertex.

Comment: @0xbadf00d take a look at the book: condition (3,1,3,1) states that $A$ has to be uniformly elliptic, so yes, $\Delta$ will do. And no, there are no further assumptions on $\partial \Omega$. However, it is known that convexity is essential, even in dimension $d=2$, so I would guess tip on failure of boundary regularity for equations on non-convex polyhedra.

Comment: @DelioMugnolo Do you know if the same can be shown in the case $d=3$ for the Stokes problem? I know that [it's true for $d=2$](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022123676900355). I've asked for that in a [separate question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/263891/regularity-of-the-stokes-problem-in-a-polyhedron).

Comment: @0xbadf00d Sorry, I cannot help you.